# react-native-meteor Meteor.collection('xxx').findOne() return undefined, how to make a callback

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-meteor

When I'm trying to get data I got undefined, but in one second after recalling the method again I get what I want. How I understand, I just wait for a response and when I try to return an object, I have nothing because it is on his way to me. .findOne() hasn't callback, what I can do in this situation?

```
  handleLogin = () => {
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.state.loginField,this.state.passwordField,(error)=>{
          if (!error) {
          Meteor.subscribe('xxx')
            let data = Meteor.collection('xxxy').findOne();
            console.log(data);
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this section of [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe). It says

> The onReady callback is called with no arguments when the server marks the subscription as ready.

Basically `Meteor.subscribe()` allows you to include callback which is called when the subscription is ready. It might look like below.

```
Meteor.subscribe('xxx', function () {
  const data = Meteor.collection('xxxy').findOne()
  console.log(data)
})
```